# Printing from a website to a printer configured on web server

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a website(asp.net) that would allow users to print to a configured printers in the application. what i mean  by that is website will have a configuration with list of available printers and from any page a user will be allowed to choose a printer from the configured list  to print to.
 so how would i set up printers on the web server?

any ideas if there are any products or how it could be done?

Appreciate your help
Thanks

Comment: You setup printers on the web server, from the web server it self. I hope that you not believe that after you setup the printer on server you going to print on clients browser.